# How to delete duplicate entry using a cursor

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

The picture attached has two tables table 1 and table 2

**Table 1:**

```
+-------------------------------------------------+--+
| First_name  Last_name Date_of_birth Customer_ID |  |
+-------------------------------------------------+--+
| ---------   ---------   ---------     -------   |  |
| Anmol        Sharma    12/SEP/1988     A101     |  |
| Anmol        Sharma    12/SEP/1988     A102     |  |
| Pushkar      Gupta     03/feb/1987     A103     |  |
| Pushkar      Gupta     03/Feb/1987     A104     |  |
+-------------------------------------------------+--+
```

**Table 2:**

```
First_name  Last_name  Date_of_birth   Customer_ID   Updated_timestamp
---------       --------- -------------- ------------ ---------------
Anmol            Sharma      12/SEP/1988      A101        23/Feb/2015
Anmol            Sharma      12/SEP/1988      A102        24/FEb/2015
Anmol            Sharma      12/SEP/1988      A101        25/Feb/2015
Pushkar          Sharma      03/FEB/1987      A104        12/Jan/2015
```

**Desired Output:**

```
First_name   Last_name Date_of_birth    Customer_ID 
---------   --------- --------------    ------------
Anmol       Sharma        12/SEP/1988      A101
Pushar      Sharma        03/FEB/1987      A104
```

**Question :**

I have to keep the recent updated Customer_ID(using table2 updated timestamp column) in table1 and delete all the other entries in table 1 using a cursor.
tables images

Can someone please explain the logic using cursor.

Comment: is it oracle or mysql? do you need to use a cursor or a query is fine?

Comment: Is it a sort of homework? If not, it is better (simpler) to use pure SQL only, without cursors.

Comment: @fthiella i need to use cursor only

Comment: @Dmitry i want to use cusrsor,but can you provide me the sql,want to see the logic

Answer (score 1):

With pure SQL it will be:

```
delete from table1
 where customer_id in (
         select customer_id
           from (select customer_id, 
                        row_number() over 
                          (partition by last_name, first_name 
                           order by updated_timestamp desc) rn
                   from table2) t
          where rn > 1)
```

Before deletion execute every subquery separately to make sure that it is correct. In first subquery `row_number()` function return 1 for most recently updated row, 2 - for second, etc. Second subquery selects all `ID`s except most recent (`rn > 1`), and it is ID's to delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE Customer_ID NOT IN 
(SELECT Customer_ID from table2 
GROUP BY Customer_ID 
ORDER BY Updated_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: i can not use customer id if it is not in group by statement

Answer (score 0):

Use the rowid pseudocolumn.

`DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3);`

Where column1, column2, and column3 make up the identifying key for each record. You might list all your columns.